# Formula not being calculated in Java Class Method

Tags: java

Java 11.6 
I am new to Java and trying to create a BMI calculator that will take in Person's weight, height and calculate the BMI. The program takes in the data but does not show any answer for the BMI calculation. Since there are no errors, I am not sure if my algorithm is wrong or basic coding error.

**The PersonWeight.java class**

```
import java.time.Year;


public class PersonWeight {


    private double height;
    private double weight;

    public PersonWeight() {

        height = 0;
        weight = 0;

    }

    public PersonWeight(double h, double w) {

        height = h;
        weight = w;

    }



    public void setHeight(double h) {
        this.height = h;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setWeight(double w) {
        this.weight = w;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }



    public double ComputeBMI() {

        double bmi = ((weight)/(height*height));
        return bmi;
    }



}
```

**The test class that has the main method**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestPersonWeight {



    public static void classifyBMI() {
        PersonWeight test1 = new PersonWeight();
        String result="";

        if(test1.ComputeBMI() < 18.5) {
            result = "Underweight ";

        } else if (test1.ComputeBMI() < 25) {
            result = "Normal Weight ";
        }else if (test1.ComputeBMI() < 30) {
            result = "Over Weight ";
        }else  {
            result = "Obese ";
        }
     System.out.printf(result);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        TestPersonWeight TestPersonWeight = new TestPersonWeight();
        PersonWeight PersonWeight = new PersonWeight()
        System.out.printf("Enter person's Height in Meters: ");
        double h = input.nextDouble();
        PersonWeight.setHeight(h);


        System.out.printf("Enter person's Weight in Kilograms: ");
        double w = input.nextDouble();
        PersonWeight.setWeight(w);

       PersonWeight.ComputeBMI();
        System.out.printf("%n Height: " + PersonWeight.getHeight());
        System.out.printf("%n Weight: " + PersonWeight.getWeight());
        System.out.printf("%n BMI: " , PersonWeight.ComputeBMI());

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the out put of `System.out.printf("%n BMI: " , PersonWeight.ComputeBMI());`

Comment: Does the program end when you run `TestPersonWeight`

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi "BMI: _______ (empty nothing shows up)"

Comment: @papaya The program displays the user height and weight but for BMI it does not display anything

Comment: `System.out.printf("%n BMI: " , PersonWeight.ComputeBMI());` why are you putting a comma here?? Replace it with `+`

Comment: @papaya that worked! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has an error in the last `System.out.printf()` command

```
System.out.printf("%n BMI: " + PersonWeight.ComputeBMI());
 //Should be plus and not a comma (",")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you're using `printf` the wrong way. You have some options:

```
System.out.printf("%nHeight: %f", PersonWeight.getHeight());
System.out.printf("%nWeight: %f", PersonWeight.getWeight());
System.out.printf("%nBMI: %f", PersonWeight.ComputeBMI());
```

Or just use `System.out.println`:

```
System.out.println("Height: " + PersonWeight.getHeight());
System.out.println("Weight: " + PersonWeight.getWeight());
System.out.println("BMI: " + PersonWeight.ComputeBMI());
```

Basically, your problem is you're using a comma in the last statement, so it's not being printed, but I'm showing you other options too.